# How to implement? Spreadsheet with link - Go To Link Grab Data - Update Spreadsheet Row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, implementation

I am looking for technology suggestions. Or if this can be done in native google sheets (note the site I am looking to access is behind a username and password).

I have a google sheet that looks like this

| birth date | link | data_element_from_website |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/31 | https://something.com/3920230 |  |
| 1/31 | https://something.com/1920238 |  |

lets say on https://something.com/3920230 there is a HTML element 123

Twice a day I want to be able to refresh the data, this could be done by going into the spreadsheet and clicking/doing something.

Can this be done?

**What if https://something.com/3920230 is behind a login (authentication).** Note: I could be logged in to the website in a different tab... I don't think that would make a difference though...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a script that you would like to run twice a day, you can use [Apps Script Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers):

> A time-driven trigger (also called a clock trigger) is similar to a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) in Unix. Time-driven triggers let scripts execute at a particular time or on a recurring interval, as frequently as every minute or as infrequently as once per month. (Note that an [add-on](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/overview) can use a time-driven trigger [once per hour at most](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#limitations).)

If it's just some formulae, you can change the recalculation settings to be either `On change`, `On change and every minute` or `On change and every hour` under the `File > Spreadsheet settings` menu item and clicking on the `Calculation` tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from public site(no login) you can use ImportXML. You can google a lot about it, for example

https://answerbun.com/personal-finance-money/get-revenue-details-in-google-sheets-using-google-finance/

If the page you want can only be accessed using login, this becomes a rather complicated task, especially using only apps script libraries (not much scraping lib support here)